# How to handle multiple actions when Serial Port data received

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I defined a Serial port (C# / .Net) and then assigned a **SerialDataReceivedEventHandler** for whenever data is received.

```
myPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler (myEventHandler);
```

However, whenever data is received, I need to do multiple things including:

- Save the data to my SQL database.
- Update a RichTextBox on the UI
- Send back a response Serial message

Should I run all these functions from within **myEventHandler**; is that the correct practice? The problem is that, for example, when I try to change a **RichTextBox** from within **myEventHandler**, I get an error stating that I'm doing cross-thread-operation.

**UPDATE:**

```
private void myEventHandler (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Action myAction = () => rtbMyRichTextBox.Text = InputMessageString;
    if (rtbMyRichTextBox.InvokeRequired)
        rtbMyRichTextBox.Invoke(myAction);
    else
        myAction();

    StoreToSqlDatabase ();

    SerialWriteResponseMessage ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do all of them within that event handler, or in methods that it calls.

You solve the cross-thread problem by synchronizing with the UI thread. If this is a Windows Forms application, you want to use [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) and [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx). Those documentation links have good examples.

Documentation for [SerialPort.DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) says:

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do the work on the proper thread.

The code would look something like:

```
void myEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSqlUpdate();
    this.Invoke(UpdateUI, data);  // pass whatever data that needs to be updated
    SendResponseMessage();
}
```

Comment: How about something like my Update above?

Comment: @boardbite: That should work. Although you can use `this.InvokeRequired` and `this.Invoke`.

Comment: Well noted. Is the cross-thread problem only of concern with the **UI update** thread? Or will I run into cross-thread issues as well with **SQL database communication** running on a separate thread, and **Serial Write** on yet another thread?

Comment: @boardbite: I wouldn't expect you to have trouble with the serial port, provided of course that you don't have two threads sending data at the same time. That would probably cause problems. You won't have trouble with SQL server if your update always opens and closes a new connection. I don't know enough about SQL Server to know if you can use a single connection from multiple threads.